# Grails 3.0.9 createLink in my gsp is not working

Tags: grails

I am trying to display an image stored in my model using the following:

`<img src="${createLink(controller:'attachments', action:'showImage', id: attachmentInstance.id)}" />`

Here is the showImage method in controller attachments:

```
def showImage= {
println "In showImage"
    def attachmentInstance = Attachment.get(params.id)
    byte[] b = attachmentInstance.image
    response.setContentLength(b.length)
    response.getOutputStream().write(b) 
}
```

Here is my domain class:

```
class Attachment {
byte[] image
String imageType 
int imageSize
String attachmentType
String fileName

static mapping = {
    image(sqlType: "blob")
    columns {
         '*'(nullable: true)
    }                   
}
```

}

The action is not being executed,  I have a prinlin to varify that.

The image is in the file and this code has been used in previous version of Grails.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug?

Comment: I'm pretty sure controller methods have to be methods now days and not closures. So `def showImage() { ... }` instead of `def showImage = { ... }` ... That's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old versions of Grails controllers used closures and not methods. Newer versions uses actual methods on the controllers and not closures. So your method should be:

```
def showImage() {
...
}
```

and not

```
def showImage = {
...
}
```

Comment: That did it!   Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. You might want to accept the answer so others know it solved the problem too.